# how to create a dynamic menu of items

Tags: html, hibernate, jsp

hey i'm trying to create an it ticketing system for a college project and im stuck trying to create a page in jsp where i take in N items from my database for which i use hibernate to interface with where all the tickets or x amount are displayed in separate boxes per ticket where it shows the title and the description of the ticket as well as a button that would allow me to link it to its corresponding page to fully view the ticket. i just cant seem to figured out what this kind of menu is called as every google search i have done has lead me to dead ends.

any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can utilize Bootstrap cards to do that. See their official website: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/ You can display some image/description for the ticket. So basically what you need is to render array of such cards.